# Android\Java Sockets are too slow?

Tags: java, android, sockets

When im using the google play app to download apps it's usually about 5mb per second.
But when im using my laptop as a server that sends a 100mb byte array,
when i download (read) this array from my smartphone it's about 2.5mb  per second.

Server Code, runs on my computer.

```
class SpeedTestServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int port = 1234;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true) {
            Socket clientConn = server.accept();
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientConn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(new byte[1024 * 1024 * 100]);
            out.flush();
            clientConn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Cleint Code, runs on my smartphone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int port = 1234;
    String host = "my computer internal ip";
    Socket client = new Socket(host, port);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 100];
    int sum = 0;

    Date start = new Date();
    System.out.println("Starting! " + start.toString());

    while((sum += in.read(buffer, sum, buffer.length - sum)) != -1) {
        if (sum == 1024 * 1024 * 100) {

            Date end = new Date();
            System.out.println("Finished! " + end.toString() + " " + sum);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your read loop isn't valid. You need to check every individual `read()` result for -1, not just their sum, which can never be -1 unless either it was returned by the first `read()` or else you have executed several hundred million redundant reads at end of stream. This has nothing to do with Android or Java, it is a peculiarity of your code.

Comment: i fixed it, still really slow.